# Spring Boot and ConfigServer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

We have a SpringBoot application which is successfully comunicating with config server.
The question I have is... say we have a application properties file and a csv file in config server. 
when application starts if we want to get the contents of csv file too whats the better approach.

We are able to get it by doing a direct http connection to configserver and retreive the csv file contents

```
String url = configServerURL+"/*/*/*/example.csv";
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encode((uname + ":" + password).getBytes());

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encoded);


    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```

wanted to check what options are there.

Comment: Looks good to me. You could use RestTemplate, but that's just taste.

Comment: The config properties are also fetched using a rest call, the spring config client ensures it fetches those properties and loads into the context. So getting the files through an http call is not an bad idea.

Comment: Thanks spencergibb and Shibashis for quick responses.

Comment: One other question I have is say if I have multiple csv like example.csv and example1.csv and example2.csv. Trying to read all of them as follows String url = configServerURL+"/*/*/*/example*.csv" didnt work. Do I have to read each file separately. Is there a better approach.